# SQL/Oracle: INSTR or REGEXP?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I'm just studying for an exam and I don't get this one:

I want to find all cities in my table that ends with ville, as in Charlottesville.

Which one would be correct?

```
... WHERE INSTR(CITY,'ville') > 0; 

or 

... WHERE REGEXP_SUBSTR(B,'ville$') = 'ville'
```

Which of these two would do it? And what is wrong with the other one?

Regards
JOP

Comment: The first one doesn't do the intended work. "Which of these two would do it? And what is wrong with the other one?" --- what if you run them and see?

Comment: Ok, cause auf the dollar sign after ville, which tells SQL it needs to end with 'ville'? and INSTR would just look for cities where 'ville' is anywhere in the cityname may it the beginn or in the middle of the city. Am I right or do I miss something or am I absolutely wrong?

Comment: Great, thanks :)
One more question: Do the 0 after the set operator tells SQL look for 'ville' from the beginning on? So for example when I would say 5 instead of 0 it would look for cities with ville starting from character position 5 6 7 etc. ?

Comment: Why not a simple `LIKE`? As in `... WHERE city LIKE '%ville';` Regex's tend to be slower than a simple `LIKE` statement.

Comment: The first would be correct if rewritten as `...WHERE INSTR(CITY, 'ville') = LENGTH(CITY)-4;` or `...WHERE INSTR(CITY, 'ville', LENGTH(CITY)-4) > 0;`. Share and enjoy.